# Using .NET Core CLI, add a Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, dll

I've tring to connect oracle db from .net core but unsuccessfull.

Right now I am tring to add the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll via .net core cli using [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604462/using-net-core-cli-add-a-reference-to-a-local-dll-when-targeting-the-full-fram) but I get this error:

```
Invalid AssemblyInformationalVersion 6.121.2.20150926 ODAC RELEASE 4 on assembly
```

I have already generated package for EntityFramework.dll.

I don't know what to do for generate nuget package for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll correctly

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't yet support .net core. You can not use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework. Convert your project to ".NET Framework 4.6.1 (or other)" or wait new versions of .net core.